# Mu-plugin causes entire site to crash

Tags: mu-plugins

I think i'm probably doing something daft here. Every time i try to include this as a mu-plugin it takes down the test site though.

```
<?php
if( is_plugin_active( '/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordfence.php' ) ) {
    require_once('wp-load.php');
    $to = ‘myemail@gmail.com’;
    $subject = ‘Wordfence is down’;
    $message = ‘Wordfence is not active’;
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
```

Any ideas where i'm going wrong would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Debugging always needs to be done you. Try to accomplish this systematically. Delete line by line of your snippet until you get the line that's causing the problem. Then check the official docs of the function that's causing the problem and fix it. You might also check/search the WordPress core for similar usages.

Comment: Cough *curly quotes* cough.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`is_plugin_active`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active) isn't available for mu-plugins to use. The codex says:

> NOTE: defined in wp-admin/includes/plugin.php, so this is only available from within the admin pages, and any references to this function must be hooked to admin_init or a later action. If you want to use this function from within a template or a must-use plugin, you will need to manually require plugin.php, an example is below.

And I think there must be better ways to solve this anyway: your code will try and send you an email for every non-static HTTP request to the site, and you probably meant `!is_plugin_active` or `is_plugin_inactive`, and in any case these accept relative paths to the plugin files not absolute paths.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to turn on `WP_DEBUG` to see exactly what problem you're facing. The code above includes fancy quotes like `‘` and `’` and doesn't include the full path to `wp-load.php`.